# Сделать отступ при выводе записей Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Цикл вывода записей:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_event_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'Детские'
        )
    )
);

$q = new WP_Query($args); if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); 
// Данные поста
endwhile; endif;
```

Нужно сделать вывод записей, после 6 offset=6
Пробовал отфильтровать так:

```
$q = new WP_Query($args, 'offset=6');
```

и

```
'post_type'         =>  'event',
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'offset'            => 6,
```

Не помогает

Comment: почему ты сразу offset не пропишешь в $args?

Comment: @SeVlad я же написал что пробовал его прописать в $args, не работает.

Comment: Но это именно так и делается и второй вариант должен быть рабочим.

Answer (score 0):

Работе мешался

```
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
```

Убрал и всё заработало.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'event',
    'offset'            => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy_event_cat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'Детские'
        )
    )
);

$q = new WP_Query($args); if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
```